# Design pattern for permissions management

Tags: java, desktop-application

Here's my problem: I'm working on an application where the users have certain rights. Depending on these rights, they would have access to some functions.

My problem is that I would have to test for every case if the user has the rights 
or not and enable it or not. For a big app, this task is quite tiring. I want to ask if there is a design pattern or library that simplifies the management of this.  My goal is to disable buttons when the user does not have proper permissions.

Comment: Looks like this might help a bit. http://www.coderanch.com/t/579141/GUI/java/session-desktop-application

Comment: Maybe, my question was badly written but my problem isn't that I want to create a session but I need a way to block a button and make it impossible to enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple things needs to be considered for such a solution

In an idea scenario, I will have following way of dealing with this problem.

1. I will have user belonging to USergroup and Roles assigned to each 
   Usergroup  in some database.
2. When the user logins to the application, you can fetch the
   usergroup and associated user roles from the database.
3. Using the roles , you can create a map to store functionaNames/field names  which
   has access.
4. Pass this map in the session scope and using its values,
   enable/disable fields & buttons.
5. Best way is to have a custom tag implemented for fields & buttons to be used in the jsp
   and then passing the map object to such tags which will validate the
   map and accordingly show the field or hide it.

Just want to keep it short and simple.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't consider the possibility of hiding the buttons but this would be much easier than testing every possible click and way that activates each button. Actually, I've done everything until 4 but I was having trouble with the 5 part.